# Trouble with debugging tar in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to debug tar part of my bash script. When I use quotes around the file names tar just doesn't see the file.

I tried to echo the tar line into file and it works. But when running the script the file is not found

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
code=0
paths=""

fatal_check() {
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
        exit 2
    elif [[ $1 != "-z" && $1 != "-h" && $1 != "" ]]; then
        echo $1
        echo "unknown options"
        exit 2
    elif [[ $2 != "-z" && $2 != "-h" && $2 != "" ]]; then
        echo $2
        echo "unknown options"
        exit 2
    fi
}

fatal_check $1 $2
if [[ $1 == "-h" || $2 == "-h" ]]; then
    echo ""
    echo "bash script to infer file types and gather more information about them"
    echo ""
    echo "OPTIONS"
    echo -e "-h \t shows this help"
    echo -e "-z \t zips all regular files"
    exit 0
fi

while read stdin; do
    if [[ $stdin == "PATH "* ]]; then

        path=${stdin:5}

        if [[ -L "$path" ]]; then
            echo LINK "'$path'" "'$(readlink "$path")'"; fatal_check
        elif [[ -d "$path" ]]; then
            echo DIR "'$path'"
        elif [[ -f "$path" ]]; then
            wc=$(wc -l < "$path"); fatal_check
            ln=$(head -n 1 "$path"); fatal_check
            echo FILE "'$path'" $wc "'$ln'"
            if [[ $1 == "-z" || $2 == "-z" ]]; then
                paths="${paths}'${path}' "
            fi
        else
            >&2 echo ERROR "'$path'"
            code=1
        fi

    fi
done

if [[ $paths != "" ]]; then
    tar czf output.tgz $paths; fatal_check
fi

exit $code
```

This is what tar throws at me. Once again when I actually echo the same line to file and run it as a command it runs normal.

```
tar: './test': Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: You would be better to use the bash array variables to build up your multiple paths variable, then use "$paths[@]" to expand it into distinct quoted paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a reasonable treatment to enclose each filename with single quotes
considering filenames containing whitespaces.
The problem is when passing the variable "$paths" to `tar` as an argument,
the single quotes are literally interpreted as a part of the filename.
Please try:

```
echo "$paths" | xargs tar czf output.tgz; fatal_check
```

in place of:

```
tar czf output.tgz $paths; fatal_check
```

Note that we need to assume the original filenames do not contain the single quotes.
Hope this helps.